Linker error in calling a subroutine of a library
I've created a simple shared library in Fortran and used it in a test program. The library module contains a subroutine in a file named my_module.f90 that is:
  ! my_module.f90

   module my_module

       contains

       subroutine my_subroutine()
          print *, "Hello from my_subroutine!"
       end subroutine my_subroutine

   end module my_module

I compiled it, using the below command:
gfortran -shared -fPIC my_module.f90 -o libmy_library.so

I created a file named test_program.f90:
   ! test_program.f90

    program main
       implicit none
       external :: my_subroutine
       call my_subroutine()
    end program main

when I compile the test program with the shared library:
gfortran test_program.f90 -o test_program -L. -lmy_library

it failed due to
undefined reference to `my_subroutine_'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

How can this issue be resolved?

Welcome, please use tag [tag:fortran] for Fortran questions. Tags are very important on Stack Overflow so that the right people will see your question. Fortran 90 is just one very old version of the standard, it is not really used despite the .f90 file extension.

When using modules,  you have to use use in the calling code and you most not use external. Forget the bind(C) thing at tthe moment, it may become useful, but later with more experience and more complicated programming.

Because of name mangling, your subroutine has different name in your .so file:
[gmt@arch ~]$ nm libmy_library.so 
                 w __cxa_finalize@GLIBC_2.2.5
0000000000004020 d __dso_handle
0000000000003dd8 d _DYNAMIC
00000000000011d4 t _fini
                 U _gfortran_st_write_done@GFORTRAN_8
                 U _gfortran_st_write@GFORTRAN_8
                 U _gfortran_transfer_character_write@GFORTRAN_8
0000000000003fe8 d _GLOBAL_OFFSET_TABLE_
                 w __gmon_start__
0000000000002028 r __GNU_EH_FRAME_HDR
0000000000001000 t _init
                 w _ITM_deregisterTMCloneTable
                 w _ITM_registerTMCloneTable
0000000000001139 T __my_module_MOD_my_subroutine
                 U __stack_chk_fail@GLIBC_2.4
0000000000004028 d __TMC_END__

you can use BIND(C,... to resolve this.
subroutine my_subroutine() BIND(C,NAME="my_subroutine_")
   print *, "Hello from my_subroutine!"
end subroutine my_subroutine 

EDIT: Don't do this. I added the nm output just to show name mangling. It's better to use USE my_module or USE my_module, ONLY: my_subroutine.

This is terrible advice.

Actually I know, but I didn't get thee point of compiling fortran module as shared library. my comment was just about undefined reference to my_subroutine_ error. I add output of nm to show the OP what linker see.

I will delete my post after about an hour.

You cannot delete an accepted answer.

Yes, I can't delete my answer. Since it is accepted. So I'll edit my post.
